# Add custom item on existing Android Application (Like a add-on or plugging kind of thing)?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I want to modify the standard messaging application in android to include some more options. Like when user long presses a message, it would open a Message option, which contain delete message, Forward etc. I wanted add my custom option of "Reply YO". Can we build a plugging or add-on to achieve this.

Comment: "Can we build a plugging or add-on to achieve this." - No. You can download the source, change it, and recompile it, but unless an app has been written to work with plugins, you can't really do that. That said, the SMS API is rather simple. You could just create your own messaging app.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike. I agree that the SMS application is fairly simple, but it involves a lot of functionality, and as a beginner I dont think thats a right course of action for me. Do you know any open source SMS application whose code is available as an standalone project. I tried AOSP messaging app but this is happening ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566021/developing-customized-version-of-built-in-sms-mms-android-application